# Union of dict with typed keys not compatible with an empty dict

Tags: mypy, python-typing

I'd like to type a dict as either a dictionary where the all the keys are integers or a dictionary where all the keys are strings.

However, when I read mypy (v0.991) on the following code:

```py
from typing import Union, Any

special_dict: Union[dict[int, Any], dict[str, Any]]

special_dict = {}
```

I get an `Incompatible types` error.

```
test_dict_nothing.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]", variable has type "Union[Dict[int, Any], Dict[str, Any]]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How do I express my typing intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `mypy` bug, already reported [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6463) with priority 1. There is a simple workaround suggested:

```py
from typing import Any

special_dict: dict[str, Any] | dict[int, Any] = dict[str, Any]()
```

This code typechecks [successfully](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=ebb080cada902b80bb37552a4e3cd1c6), because you basically give `mypy` a hint with more specific type of your dictionary. It may be any matching type and won't affect further checking, because you broaden the final type with an explicit type hint.